# "PlayerAdded" script even working after player's death. How to fix?

Tags: lua, roblox

I tried to create this script where I create a Loading Screen that should be working only once as PlayerAdded function is intended. But when a player dies, the Loading Screen comes back. What's wrong?

I used two types of Player added. The normal PlayerAdded doesn't work when there's only one player, considering the server has just started and avoids player's scripts. The second one gives me this problem.

```
function onPlayerAdded(Player)
    local PlayerGui = game.Players.LocalPlayer:WaitForChild("PlayerGui") 
    PlayerGui:SetTopbarTransparency(0)
    local LoadingScreen = Player.PlayerGui.LoadingScreen
    ...
end

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(onPlayerAdded)

for _, player in pairs(game.Players:GetPlayers()) do
    onPlayerAdded(player)
end
```

Comment: I do not understand the for-loop you have there. The line `game:GetService("Players").PlayerAdded:Connect(onPlayerAdded)` sets `onPlayerAdded` to be called whenever the `PlayerAdded` event fires, which occurs whenever a new player enters the game. Explicitly calling that function with the for-loop should be unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ReplicatedFirst:

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(plr)
game.ReplicatedFirst.LoadingScreen:Clone().Parent = plr.PlayerGui
end)

Sorry if I made any mistakes, I have not programmed in roblox for a while plus I am on phone.

Answer (score 0):

I envision something like this:

```lua
local players = game:GetService("Players")

-- Assume the loading GUI is a child of script.
local gui = script:WaitForChild("LoadingGui")

local function onPlayerAdded(player)
    local playerGui = player:WaitForChild("PlayerGui")
    local clone = playerGui:FindFirstChild("LoadingGui")
    if (not clone) then
        clone = gui:Clone()
        clone.Parent = playerGui
    end
    return
end
players.PlayerAdded:Connect(onPlayerAdded)
```

`onPlayerAdded` should only fire once per client, so the GUI should only appear once as intended. Also, it is a good idea to put this code in a `Script`, not a `LocalScript`, within `ServerScriptStorage`.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem seems to be that the local script is being recreated with the player. I assume that is because this script is inside of the player's StarterGui or in StarterCharacterScripts. The solution would be to move this script into StarterPlayerScripts or ReplicatedFirst.

Another problem is that PlayerAdded is fired when any player joins. This is on a local script so whenever someone else joins the loading screen will appear, which is most likely not intended. PlayerAdded should be removed completely in order to fix this, the script will be run automatically when the current player is added anyways. The loop is also unnecessary because of this.